# Read any JSON into list of key-value pairs (EAV format) in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, entity-attribute-value

Looking for a way to read any JSON without knowing the internals with SQL Server's JSON methods, I came up with an approach I'd like to share.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60955104/5089204) is the question bringing up this issue.

The question is: How can I transform an unknown JSON into a structured EAV format while keeping all the information about sort order and nest levels.

The ideal output should carry the original row's id as the *entity*, the Json's key and value as the *attribute* and *value* together with the JsonPath for the specific object in a sorted list.

Find the MCVE (sample data from the linked question) embedded into my self-answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we create a declared table variable and fill it with some sample JSONs to simulate the issue (I added some arrays to the samples to reflect JSON paths for arrays):

```sql
DECLARE @table TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, AnyJSON NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
(N' {
    "correlationId": "c3xOeEEQQCCA9sEx7-u6FA",
    "eventCreateTime": "2020-05-12T15:38:23.717Z",
    "time": 1589297903717,
    "owner": {
        "ownergeography": {
            "city": "abc",
            "country": "abc"
        },
        "ownername": {
            "firstname": "abc",
            "lastname": "def"
        },
        "clientApiKey": "xxxxx",
        "businessProfileApiKey": null,
        "userId": null
    },
    "campaignType": "Mobile push"
}')
,(N'[{
    "correlationIds": [
        {
            "campaignId": [1,2,3],
            "correlationId": [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"}]
        }
    ],
    "variantId": 1278915,
    "utmCampaign": "",
    "ua.os.major": "8"
    }
    ,{
    "correlationIds": [
        {
            "campaignId": [1,2,3],
            "correlationId": [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"}]
        }
    ],
    "variantId": 1278915,
    "utmCampaign": "",
    "ua.os.major": "8"
    }]')
,(N'{
    "correlationId": "ls7XmuuiThWzktUeewqgWg",
    "eventCreateTime": "2020-05-12T12:40:20.786Z",
    "time": 1589287220786,
    "modifiedBy": {
        "clientId": null,
        "clientApiKey": "xxx",
        "businessProfileApiKey": null,
        "userId": null
    },
    "campaignType": "Mobile push"
}');
```

--The query

```sql
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,NestLevel   = 0 
          ,ObjectIndex = CAST(1 AS bigint)                                                          
          ,SortString  = CAST(N'sort'                       COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 

          ,JsonPath    = CAST(N'$'                          COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
          ,JsonKey     = CAST(N'$'                          COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
          ,JsonValue   = CAST(AnyJSON                       COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
          ,JsonType    = CAST(CASE WHEN LEFT(TRIM(AnyJSON),1)=N'[' THEN 4 ELSE 0 END AS TINYINT)
          ,NestedJSON  = CAST(CASE WHEN ISJSON(AnyJSON)=1 
                                   THEN AnyJSON 
                                   ELSE NULL END            COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM @table t

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.ID
          ,r.NestLevel+1
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
          ,CAST(CONCAT(r.SortString,REPLACE(STR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),5),' ','0')) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

          ,CAST(CONCAT(r.JsonPath, CASE WHEN r.JsonType=4 --<-- see the docs for OPENJSON()
                                        THEN CONCAT('[',A.[key],']') 
                                        ELSE '.' + A.[key] END)                       COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
          ,CAST(A.[key]                                                               COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
          ,CAST(r.JsonValue                                                           COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
          ,A.[type] 
          ,CAST(A.[value]                                                             COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM recCTE r
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(r.NestedJSON) A
    WHERE ISJSON(r.NestedJSON)=1
)
SELECT ID
      ,NestLevel
      ,ObjectIndex
      ,JsonPath
      ,JsonKey
      ,NestedJSON AS JsonValue
      ,SortString --<-- just to illustrate the sorting, not needed in the output
FROM recCTE 
WHERE ISJSON(NestedJSON)=0
ORDER BY ID,SortString;
```

The result

```
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| ID | JsonPath                                  | JsonKey         | JsonValue                | SortString                      |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | $.correlationId                           | correlationId   | c3xOeEEQQCCA9sEx7-u6FA   | 0    1                          |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | $.eventCreateTime                         | eventCreateTime | 2020-05-12T15:38:23.717Z | 0    2                          |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | $.time                                    | time            | 1589297903717            | 0    3                          |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | $.owner.ownergeography.city               | city            | abc                      | 0    4    1    1                |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | $.owner.ownergeography.country            | country         | abc                      | 0    4    1    2                |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | $.owner.ownername.firstname               | firstname       | abc                      | 0    4    2    1                |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | $.owner.ownername.lastname                | lastname        | def                      | 0    4    2    2                |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | $.owner.clientApiKey                      | clientApiKey    | xxxxx                    | 0    4    3                     |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | $.campaignType                            | campaignType    | Mobile push              | 0    5                          |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[0].correlationIds[0].campaignId[0]      | 0               | 1                        | 0    1    1    1    1    1      |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[0].correlationIds[0].campaignId[1]      | 1               | 2                        | 0    1    1    1    1    2      |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[0].correlationIds[0].campaignId[2]      | 2               | 3                        | 0    1    1    1    1    3      |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[0].correlationIds[0].correlationId[0].a | a               | b                        | 0    1    1    1    2    1    1 |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[0].correlationIds[0].correlationId[1].c | c               | d                        | 0    1    1    1    2    2    1 |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[0].correlationIds[0].correlationId[2].e | e               | f                        | 0    1    1    1    2    3    1 |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[0].variantId                            | variantId       | 1278915                  | 0    1    2                     |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[0].utmCampaign                          | utmCampaign     |                          | 0    1    3                     |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[0].ua.os.major                          | ua.os.major     | 8                        | 0    1    4                     |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[1].correlationIds[0].campaignId[0]      | 0               | 1                        | 0    2    1    1    1    1      |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[1].correlationIds[0].campaignId[1]      | 1               | 2                        | 0    2    1    1    1    2      |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[1].correlationIds[0].campaignId[2]      | 2               | 3                        | 0    2    1    1    1    3      |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[1].correlationIds[0].correlationId[0].a | a               | b                        | 0    2    1    1    2    1    1 |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[1].correlationIds[0].correlationId[1].c | c               | d                        | 0    2    1    1    2    2    1 |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[1].correlationIds[0].correlationId[2].e | e               | f                        | 0    2    1    1    2    3    1 |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[1].variantId                            | variantId       | 1278915                  | 0    2    2                     |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[1].utmCampaign                          | utmCampaign     |                          | 0    2    3                     |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | $[1].ua.os.major                          | ua.os.major     | 8                        | 0    2    4                     |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 3  | $.correlationId                           | correlationId   | ls7XmuuiThWzktUeewqgWg   | 0    1                          |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 3  | $.eventCreateTime                         | eventCreateTime | 2020-05-12T12:40:20.786Z | 0    2                          |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 3  | $.time                                    | time            | 1589287220786            | 0    3                          |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 3  | $.modifiedBy.clientApiKey                 | clientApiKey    | xxx                      | 0    4    2                     |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 3  | $.campaignType                            | campaignType    | Mobile push              | 0    5                          |
+----+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

The idea in short:

- we use a recursive CTE to walk this down.
- The query will test any fragment (`[value]` coming from `OPENJSON`) for being valid JSON.
- If the fragment is valid, this walks deeper and deeper.
- The column `SortString` is needed to get a final sort order.
- The `CAST()` and `COLLATE` helps to avoid data type mismatch. Recursive CTEs are very picky with this...

Hint: If you deal with bigger JSONs you might need to set `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` at the end of your query.

Enjoy :-)

### Something similar for XML

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61886650/5089204) is a similar answer about how to read an unknown XML.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, Well, time is the shortage :-) This approach is quite close to the recursive XML function we both know quite well :-)

Comment: Just for fun, here is how I convert JSON to a hierarchy.   Any inputs/tweaks welcome https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2292b4fdecd0c29a4e36314b52e6f007

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, great! Did you poste this here anywhere? Before I opened this self-answered question I did some research without any success...

Comment: @Shnugo No, I did not post that (I believe)