# Json query to a table?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a JSON string as shown below. How can I create a table below or similar using SQL Server with a procedure or function? Thanks all.

I'm using SQL Server 15.0.2080.9.

```
{    
    "Person": {
                  "firstName": "John",
                  "lastName": "Smith",
                  "age": 25,
                  "Address":  {
                       "streetAddress":"21 2nd Street",
                       "city":"New York",
                       "state":"NY",
                       "postalCode":"10021"
                  },
                  "PhoneNumbers": {
                       "home":"212 555-1234",
                       "fax":"646 555-4567"
                  }
            }
}
```

[image: Table]

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70843770/edit) your question to provide more information - as text. You've tagged `sql-server` but what specific version of Microsoft SQL Server do you mean? Not all supported versions of SQL Server actually support JSON queries and construction. What SQL queries have you tried so far?

Comment: @JustStartlDev, a good starting [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800927/read-any-json-into-list-of-key-value-pairs-eav-format-in-sql-server), using recursive CTE.

Comment: @zhorov, thanks, i'll read about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent starting point is this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800927/read-any-json-into-list-of-key-value-pairs-eav-format-in-sql-server), but a simplified approach (if the parsed JSON has a variable structure with nested JSON objects, but without JSON arrays) is the folowing recursive statement:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'
{    
    "Person": {
                  "firstName": "John",
                  "lastName": "Smith",
                  "age": 25,
                  "Address":  {
                       "streetAddress":"21 2nd Street",
                       "city":"New York",
                       "state":"NY",
                       "postalCode":"10021"
                  },
                  "PhoneNumbers": {
                       "home":"212 555-1234",
                       "fax":"646 555-4567"
                  }
            }
}'
```

Statement:

```
;WITH rCTE AS (
   SELECT 
      1 AS Id,
      CONVERT(nvarchar(max), NULL) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS [Parent], 
      CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'Person') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS [Key], 
      CONVERT(nvarchar(max), JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.Person')) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS [Value]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      r.Id + 1,
      CONVERT(nvarchar(max), r.[Key]) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
      CONVERT(nvarchar(max), c.[Key]) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
      CONVERT(nvarchar(max), c.[value]) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT                                        
   FROM rCTE r
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(r.[Value]) c
   WHERE ISJSON(r.[Value]) = 1
)
SELECT [Parent], [Key], [Value]
FROM rCTE
ORDER BY Id
```

Result:

| Parent | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Person | {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "age": 25, "Address": {"streetAddress":"21 2nd Street", "city":"New York", "state":"NY", "postalCode":"10021"}, "PhoneNumbers": {"home":"212 555-1234", "fax":"646 555-4567" }} |
| Person | firstName | John |
| Person | lastName | Smith |
| Person | age | 25 |
| Person | Address | {"streetAddress":"21 2nd Street", "city":"New York", "state":"NY", "postalCode":"10021"} |
| Person | PhoneNumbers | {"home":"212 555-1234", "fax":"646 555-4567"} |
| PhoneNumbers | home | 212 555-1234 |
| PhoneNumbers | fax | 646 555-4567 |
| Address | streetAddress | 21 2nd Street |
| Address | city | New York |
| Address | state | NY |
| Address | postalCode | 10021 |

Comment: How can i apply it for new json string ? if i dont know its structure

Comment: @JustStartlDev, simply assign the JSON cointent to the `@json` variable and execute the recursive statement again.

Comment: I mean, if i have a new json string in a colums, and i want to query it to a table, how can i do it, cause i see you use 
SELECT 
      1 AS Id,
      CONVERT(nvarchar(max), NULL) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS [Parent], 
      CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'Person') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS [Key], 
      CONVERT(nvarchar(max), JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.Person')) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS [Value]
   UNION ALL
after with, how can i insert another variable ? IF there is a key: value before person ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Openjson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), it would give you your desired result.

this is an example for your specific JSON:

```
DECLARE @Json NVARCHAR(max) = '{    
    "Person": {
                  "firstName": "John",
                  "lastName": "Smith",
                  "age": 25,
                  "Address":  {
                       "streetAddress":"21 2nd Street",
                       "city":"New York",
                       "state":"NY",
                       "postalCode":"10021"
                  },
                  "PhoneNumbers": {
                       "home":"212 555-1234",
                       "fax":"646 555-4567"
                  }
            }
}'

SELECT NULL AS Parent
    ,[KEY]
    ,[value]
FROM openjson(@json, '$')

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Person' AS Parent,
[KEY]
    ,[value]
FROM openjson(@json, '$.Person')

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Address'AS Parent,
[KEY]
    ,[value]
FROM openjson(@json, '$.Person.Address')

UNION ALL

SELECT 'PhoneNumbers' AS Parent ,[KEY]
    ,[value]
FROM openjson(@json, '$.Person.PhoneNumbers')
```

Comment: OMG, thanks so much, its helped me <3